# Use of the delta function in the cancellation of real and virtual corrections

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, regularization

In light of the not so well defined integral $\int_a^b \delta(x-a) dx$ and from David Z's comment at the end of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1740355/) Math.SE post, consider the following equation, which I've come across in many sources on the discussion about cancellation of real and virtual corrections leading to infrared safety results:
$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{dA(x)}{dx} + B = C = \text{finite}$$ which is then rewritten as  $$\int_0^1 dx \left( \frac{dA(x)}{dx} + (B-C)\delta(1-x) \right) = \text{finite}.$$

So, here the integral $$\int_0^1 \delta(1-x)dx = 1$$ is used which is **not** the most sensible way to define the integral of the delta function with one of the end points coinciding with the zero of the delta argument.

If we demand $$ \int_{-1}^1 \delta(x)dx = 1 = \int_{-1}^0 \delta(x)dx + \int_0^1 \delta(x)dx = \theta(0) + (1- \theta(0)) $$ then $\int_0^1 \delta(x) dx$ is not well defined in so far as $\theta(0)$ is not so well defined. But if we want both contributions on the right hand side to yield the same result then we get $\theta(0) = 1/2$ which I understand to be the frequentist value taken for the integral. So, my **question** is

1. What is the physical reasoning of allowing one to take $\int_0^1 \delta(1-x)dx = 1$ here in this particular set up?

For more context, see this page: http://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~krauss/Lectures/QuarksLeptons/QCD/DGLAP_2.html - the relevant equations are the third and fourth displays.

Comment: More on the "+"-distribution: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15132/2451

Comment: Should go to Mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a satisfactory answer unless you think about the Dirac function in another way.

You see, the Dirac function is not a function, and the fact that we call it like that makes many mathematicians angry. It is rather a distribution. You can think about distributions as something like integration measures over the space.

Let us make an example. Usually, in integrals like $\int_0^1$, you don't specify wheter you have a closed interval, an open interval or a mixed one. This is because this choice does not matter for standard integrals. With this distribution, the detail is crucial.

A measure on the space is usually given in terms of a function that weighs the different areas, but in the case of Dirac distribution (let us use proper names) the definition is different: the distribution $\delta(x-x_0)$ acts on sets $A$ as
$$
\delta(x-x_0)(A)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1&\text{if}\;x_0\in A\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.
$$
This distribution is assigned by assigning values on sets. In this case the question can be well posed: if you mean an integral over $(0,1]$ or $[0,1]$, the integral of the Dirac delta (or else, the measure of the interval) is $1$, else it is $0$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53937/discussion-on-answer-by-salvatore-baldino-use-of-the-delta-function-in-the-cance).